# Show missing dates when joining on calendar table and filtering on certain users

Tags: mysql, sql

I have generated a `calendar` table, containing every date from 2000-01-01 until 2050-12-31.

Apart from that I also have the `user` table, this table contains the following columns:

```
id, created, is_profile_public
```

And lastly, I have a table which links my users to 1 or many organisations (this is optional, not every user will be linked to an organisation). This table is called `user_organisation`.

I want to fetch data for statistical purposes where I get the data from the earliest create date of my user until yesterday. And missing dates should just contain 0 values in every column.

I have created this query:

```
SELECT c.datefield, DATE(u.created) AS created, 
   SUM(case when u.is_profile_public=1 AND uo.user_id is null then 1 else 0 end) as amount_public_volunteers, 
   SUM(case when u.is_profile_public=0 AND uo.user_id is null then 1 else 0 end) as amount_private_volunteers, 
   SUM(case when u.is_profile_public=1 AND uo.user_id is not null then 1 else 0 end) as amount_public_volunteers_admin, 
   SUM(case when u.is_profile_public=0 AND uo.user_id is not null then 1 else 0 end) as amount_private_volunteers_admin
FROM calendar AS c
LEFT OUTER JOIN user AS u ON c.datefield = DATE(u.created)
LEFT JOIN (select max(organisation_id), user_id from user_organisation group by user_id) AS uo on uo.user_id=u.id
WHERE u.id IN (87,  89, 172, 185, 186, 341, 342, 343, 344, 443, 444, 445,
  446, 455, 459, 463,  20,  94,  61, 100, 101, 102, 109, 112,
  113, 115, 132, 166, 184, 198, 199, 203, 205, 206, 207, 271,
  272, 273, 274, 275, 276, 277, 280, 278, 279, 281, 284, 282,
  283, 285, 288, 286, 287, 289, 292, 290, 291, 293, 294, 295,
  302, 303, 304, 305, 306, 307, 308, 309, 310, 311, 312, 313,
  318, 314, 316, 315, 319, 317, 324, 325, 326, 328, 330, 332,
  340, 358, 369, 383, 384, 391, 395, 396, 397, 398, 405, 399,
  406, 400, 409, 401) AND (c.datefield BETWEEN (SELECT MIN(DATE(created)) FROM user) AND DATE(NOW()))
GROUP BY c.datefield
```

This shows me only the dates on which the users have been created. But it does not give me any rows back on the dates where no users were created.

Comment: If you use LEFT join then all conditions by right table/subquery must be applied in ON, not in WHERE. Move the condition by `u.id`.

Comment: another thing to do  ( u.id IN (..your ids...) or u.id is null)

Comment: @Akina thank you very much this was the solution! If you can post it as an answer i will mark it as accepted!